# почему не выходит правильный результат

Tags: python, математика

[image: выражение]

Пользователь через пробел вводит значение двух переменных,подставить и решить выражение ,но ответ не совпадает с примером.Входные данные - 1.000 -2.000.
Выходные данные - 4.000.

```
from math import sqrt
x, y = map(float, input().split())
answer = (((x-y)**2)/sqrt(x**2 + y ** 2 - 1) + (sqrt(x**2+y**2-1)/2*x*y))
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте круглые скобки вокруг `2*x*y`:

```
answer = (((x-y)**2)/sqrt(x**2 + y ** 2 - 1) + (sqrt(x**2+y**2-1)/(2*x*y)))
```